# Show that $3x^2 - 7y^2 = 1$ has no integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Show that $3x^2 - 7y^2 = 1$ has no integer solutions

- A bit confused with this problem, my professor gave me a hint saying that I would need to use a "good mod" although I am not sure how to go about this, any help is greatly appreciated, I looked over a few similar posts on stack and still don't quite understand. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Work modulo $7$. The inverse of $3$ is $5$, so any solution $x$ is a solution of $x^2\equiv 5\pmod{7}$. However, it is easy to check that $5$ is not a quadratic residue of $7$.

More simply, we can work modulo $3$, since it is clear that the congruence $-y^2\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ does not have a solution.

Comment: Is it possible to work mod 6?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: We could have more simply worked modulo $3$.  For if the equation holds, then $-y^2\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, which is impossible.

Comment: Exactly. My question is, what is the nature of the set {$n:x^2-3y^2=n$ has a solution}?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  . See "Pell's equation."

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: For this (more or less) Pellian, one can find a characterization. It is helpful to work in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$. This is beyond the level of the current question, but might be an interesting question to ask.

Comment: Thank you, @user254665 that was useful.